# License of the used Bootstrap Theme is not GPL compatible

Tags: theme-development, licensing

I have made theme using material design html & css https://github.com/FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design. But my theme is no getting approve because License of the used Bootstrap Theme is not GPL compatible, see https://github.com/FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design/blob/master/LICENSE.md.
How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

> You can use this software for free only for no-profit projects.

This restriction is not compatible with the GPL [which says](http://opensource.org/licenses/GPL-3.0#section2):

> This License explicitly affirms your unlimited permission to run the unmodified Program.

Either ask the author to put the code under a [GPL compatible license](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.en.html#GPLCompatibleLicenses), or remove that dependency from your code.